# Getting a nullpointer exception when switching displayables in J2ME

Tags: forms, java-me

So I'm adding a form to my J2ME application but always get a nullpointer exception when trying to go back to the main screen. This does not seem to happen when I'm using a canvas, I can successfully go back to the main menu. What gives?

Starting the form from the main midlet

```
quickAlarm = new QuickAlarm("Set quick alarm",this);
                display.setCurrent(quickAlarm);
```

Constructor in QuickAlarm

```
public QuickAlarm(String title,HelloMIDlet midlet) {
      super(title);
      df = new DateField("Alarm time",DateField.TIME);
      this.append(df);
      this.midlet = midlet;

      backCommand = new Command("Back",Command.BACK,0);
      saveCommand = new Command("Save",Command.OK,1);

      this.addCommand(backCommand);
      this.addCommand(saveCommand);
    }
```

Going back to the main menu from QuickAlarm,

```
this.midlet.leaveCanvas();
```

This is in the main midlet

```
 public void leaveCanvas() {
      display.setCurrent(startOptions);
 }
```

The full error is

```
TRACE: <at java.lang.NullPointerException:   0>, Exception caught in Display class
java.lang.NullPointerException:   0
        at javax.microedition.lcdui.Display$ChameleonTunnel.callScreenListener(), bci=46
        at com.sun.midp.chameleon.layers.SoftButtonLayer.processCommand(), bci=74
        at com.sun.midp.chameleon.layers.SoftButtonLayer.soft1(), bci=37
        at com.sun.midp.chameleon.layers.SoftButtonLayer.keyInput(), bci=36
        at com.sun.midp.chameleon.CWindow.keyInput(), bci=38
        at javax.microedition.lcdui.Display$DisplayEventConsumerImpl.handleKeyEvent(), bci=17
        at com.sun.midp.lcdui.DisplayEventListener.process(), bci=277
        at com.sun.midp.events.EventQueue.run(), bci=179
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:637)
```

Comment: display.setCurrent(startOptions); Where is *startOptions* set?

Comment: Its defined in the main middlet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disregard, I simply forgot to setup the command listener.

Answer (score 0):

Define what is "quickAlarm" & "startOptions".you should able to pass the "Displayable" object in the "display.setCurrent()" method.So check it for "quickAlarm" & "startOptions" they are the subclass of "javax.microedition.lcdui.Displayable"